# What is the Tensorflow equivalent of numpy.random.multivariate_normal?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I want to draw random samples given mean and Co-variance matrix. In numpy I can do that using [`numpy.random.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) function. What is the Tensorflow equivalent of this?

In my case,  data is 2-D. So, mean would be a least of tensors of dimenstion (batch_size, 1) and the length of the mean list would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag`, as seen in the [TensorFlow Official Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions/multivariate_distributions).

Comment: No. In this case, I have to put observation to evaluate the pdf, What I want is to randomly draw some samples given mean and covariance. See the numpy function

Answer (score 0):

To get random samples you can use the method [sample](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Normal#sample) of the `tf.distributions.Normal` class. Instead of the co-variance matrix it requires the standard deviation. For example with 2-D:

```
mean = [1.0, 2.0]
std = [0.5, 0.7]
dist = tf.distributions.Normal(mean, std)
dist.sample()
```